# Когда было добавлено приложение в google play?

Tags: google-play, маркетинг

Провожу анализ рынка. Надо узнать, когда было добавлено [приложение конкурента](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=simon.application.AvionsPapierFull&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInNpbW9uLmFwcGxpY2F0aW9uLkF2aW9uc1BhcGllckZ1bGwiXQ..). Как это узнать?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы по маркетингу и раскрутке не относятся к тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно посмотреть историю обновлений и примерно прикинуть дату первого релиза (http://www.appbrain.com/app/paper-airplanes-full/simon.application.AvionsPapierFull , вкладка Changelog). Большее - вряд ли.

Answer (score 0):

Когда добавлено Вы не посмотрите, но можите узнать, когда было обновлено. В правой колонке, где можно шариться в google+ и twitter ниже написана инфа, что оно было обновлено 7 Ноябрь 2012 г.